# Weak convergence fails when $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is not continuous and $X_n$ converges weakly to $X$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, continuity, random-variables, weak-convergence

I understand how to derive the theorem that, if $X_n \to X$ converges in distribution, and $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $g \left(X_n \right) \to g \left(X \right)$ also converges in distribution. However, I want to see a simple example where the theorem fails.

[image]

Comment: Try $X_n=\frac X n$ where $X$ is positive and $g=I_{(-\infty, 0]}$.

Comment: Note that the theorem is true if the set $U_g$ of discontinuities of $g$ satisfies $P(X \in U_g) = 0$. So to construct a counterexample, make $g$ have continuities where $X$ puts mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $X$ a point mass at $0$ and $X_n$ a normal random variable of variance $1/n$. Then $X_n \to X$ weakly.

If $g$ is the indicator function for $[0, \infty)$ what is $g(X_n)$ for all $n$?

What is $g(X)$?

Comment: Wouldn’t g(X) be 0?

Comment: An indicator function has value $1$ on the set it is indicating, and value $0$ elsewhere. So $g(x) = 1$ for $x \in [0, \infty)$ and $g(x) = 0$ for all other $x$. Since $X = \delta_0$, with probability $1$ we have $X = 0$, and $$ g(x) = g(0) = 1.$$